# How to merge two automatic modules exporting the same package in Project Jigsaw?

Tags: java, javac, grpc-java, java-platform-module-system, module-info

The concept guide of Project Jigsaw introduces "a bridge between two automatic modules exporting the same package". [1](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#bridges-to-the-class-path)

In fact, currently both of two automatic modules `grpc.api` and `grpc.context` export `io.grpc` package, as is reported in its github. [2](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/3522)

The *bridge* seems to be the exact solution to apply Jigsaw for a project with these libraries, but the documentation does not offer any concrete way to achieve it.

Is there any `javac` command option for this purpose? Or, is there any recommended way to overcome this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how you would be running the application, but you could, for example, choose to place `grpc.api.jar` on classpath while the `grpc.context.jar` on modulepath. But remember, the `grpc.api` would not be accessible as an automatic module anymore if you do so. For `javac` command options look for `--class-path` and `--module-path` under [this document.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/javac.html)

Answer (score 1):

> „*…the documentation does not offer any concrete way to achieve it…*“

[*In this project*](https://github.com/lingocoder/springfox.docketyper) and [*in this one*](https://github.com/lingocoder/grpc.jpms.bridge.demo) I have implemented a concrete application of what Reinhold prescribes in that „[*Bridges to the class path*](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#bridges-to-the-class-path)“ documentation you linked to in your question.

> „*…is there any recommended way to overcome this situation?…*“

In addition to those two bridge-based approaches, I've also been able to solve both the Springfox and the gRPC issues using the *`--patch-module`* command line option.

But even though *`--patch-module`* is a more straightforward way to overcome the split package situation, it's „[***strongly discouraged***](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Patching-module-content)“…

> „***The --patch-module option is intended only for testing and debugging. Its use in production settings is strongly discouraged***.“